# Accessing programmatically the datetime a gravity form is submitted

Tags: php, form-submit, gravityforms

I have a simple Gravity Form for a student registration process which includes only a consent field and a few fields identifying the person consenting (parent or student). Consent is required yearly so, in addition to needing the ability to report on when consent was given, I need to have access to the date/time this consent form is submitted to keep track of this. I’m programmatically determining when this confirmation needs to be requested of a logged in user, but that requires the ability to access date/time of previous submissions. It feels like this should be straight-forward and I apologize if I’m missing something obvious. I’m sure that gravity forms stores this information for each submission because merge tags exist, but I believe I need to be able to access it from the data base so I can incorporate it in php code. I have looked through the stored data in the gf tables and I’m not seeing it. I was guessing I somehow access it through the GFAPI, but I can't see how to do it. I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for php:

```
$form_id =12;//replace with your form id #
 $search_criteria [ 'start_date' ] = '2021-01-01';
 $search_criteria [ 'end_date' ] = '2022-01-01' ;
 $entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria );//This grabs the array of entries between the dates
 foreach($entries as $entry){
     echo $entry['date_created'];//echo the date and time of each entry
 }
```